# Calculation results not displaying in totals table javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a paycheck calculator, but when I enter the hourly rate and number of hours and hit calculate, all I'm getting is *undefined* in my totals table. Here is my javascript:

```
var $ = function (id) {
return document.getElementById(id); 
}

function updateTotal () {

var rate;
var hours = parseFloat( $("numHours").value);
var regularHours;
var overtime;
var doubletime;

    //begin determine hourly rate 
    function checkJob () {
    if ($('job').value == 'job0') {
    rate = 0;
    }
    if ($('job').value == 'job1') {
    rate = 12;
    }
    if ($('job').value == 'job2') {
    rate = 10;
    }
    if ($('job').value == 'job3') {
    rate = 11;
    }
    }

    //calculate hours breakdown
    function checkHours () {
    if (hours.value <= 40) {
    regularHours = hours.value;
    overtime = 0;
    doubletime = 0;
    }

    if (hours.value < 60) {
    regularHours = 40;
    overtime = hours.value-40;
    doubletime=0;
    }

    if (hours.value >=60) {
    regularHours = 40;
    overtime = 20;
    doubletime = hours.value-60;
    }
    }

    checkJob();
    checkHours();

    var salary = (regularHours * rate) + (overtime * (rate * 1.5)) + (doubletime * (rate * 2))



    //display amounts
    $('regularHours').innerHTML = regularHours;
    $('overtime').innerHTML = overtime;
    $('doubletime').innerHTML = doubletime;
    $('salary').innerHTML = "$ " + salary;
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something silly, but I've been staring at this code for days and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

The offending code is this:

```
hours.value
```

The problem with it is that `hours` is already a number, and number does not have the method `value` available to it. Changing all instances of `hours.value` to `hours` will solve the problem and properly output a calculated result.

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gLthv/

---

<strike>The problem is the way you are implementing your jquery selectors. You should either use `document.getElementById()` instead, or remember that to select an id, you need to prefix the id name with a `#`</strike>

```
$("#id")
```

That is only the first part of the problem though. The next part is that you are using jquery, but expecting dom elements. To unwrap the jquery object, you need to use `[0]` with it to be able to access the contained dom element.

```
$("#id")[0]
```

Once you make these changes, you should be able to see the reflected calculations. For example, `$('job').value` should really be `$('#job')[0].value` or if you prefer to stick with jquery's implementation then you can use `$('#job').val()` to get the value.

Similar to this you may also access jquery's implementation of `innerHTML`. That would change this: `$('overtime').innerHTML = overtime` to `$('#overtime').html(overtime)`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add my var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id); 
}
 at the top of my cut & paste.

Comment: @user2081142 - Well that would make things a little different.

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't know what jquery is. I'm taking my first javascript class, so please bear with me if I'm a little slow.

Comment: @user2081142 - It is okay. jQuery is just an API that a lot of people use, and the shortcut character to use it is the `$` so that is why I made that assumption. I will see if there is another issue in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your help - I really appreciate it. If it would help, I can paste my HTML for my input form and my totals table. Just let me know if you want to see them. Thank you.

Comment: @TaraX - The html would definitely help. Right now I am not sure my mock of it is exactly what you are working with.

Comment: I made the change from hours.value to just hours and it is working. Thank you for all your help and patience with me!!